# A strange mathematical result from greatest integer function.

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have made a function to plot a graph of stairs with heigth '$h$' & length '$l$' ( [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/obaxe3xcss)) where I assume that $l$ & $h$ and $x$ are positive, real and not equal to zero(i.e the stairs lie in the 4th Quadrant).

Now if I take any point $\alpha$ on the $nth$ stair. The $y$ co-ordinate will be $n*h$ and the $x$ co-ordinate will be $(nl-m)$ where m is the distance from the edge of the $nth$ stair.

---

Now using the equations :-
$$\begin{align}
y &= -h\left\lfloor\frac xl+1\right\rfloor \\
-nh &= -h\left\lfloor\frac{nl-m}l + 1\right\rfloor \\
n &= \left(\left\lfloor n -\frac ml\right\rfloor + 1\right) \\
\end{align}
$$
As we know  $n$  will  be  natural}:
$$\begin{align}
n &= n -\left\lfloor\frac ml\right\rfloor + 1 \\
-1 &= -{\left\lfloor\frac ml\right\rfloor} \\
\left\lfloor\frac ml\right\rfloor &= 1 
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $m\ge l.$
But I have taken '$m$' such that it can be less than or equal to m. Therefore  $m$ will be equal to $l$. This means that every point lies on the edge. I want to know the flaw in my thinking.

---

Image of graph:-

### [image: Image of graph]

The original question I was trying to solve was if throw a ball with $u$ horizontal velocity from the top of the stairs each of height of $h$ and length $l$ then on which step it will strike and how much distance from the edge?

Comment: If $a \in \mathbb N$ then $\lfloor a - b\rfloor = a - \lceil b \rceil \ne a -\lfloor b \rfloor$.

Comment: It is not true that $\lfloor n-x\rfloor = n-\lfloor x\rfloor$ in general, if $n$ is an integer. You do have that $$\lfloor n-x\rfloor = n+\lfloor -x\rfloor=n-\lceil x\rceil.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So in my question can I say  that $\lfloor \frac{-m}l \rfloor = -1$ ?

Comment: Yes,$\lfloor \frac {-m}l \rfloor = - 1\implies \lceil \frac ml \rceil = 1\implies  0< \frac ml \le 1$

Comment: @fleablood Ok thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\lfloor n -\frac ml\rfloor + 1\ne n -\left\lfloor\frac ml\right\rfloor + 1$

$\lfloor n -\frac ml\rfloor + 1= n -\left\lceil\frac ml\right\rceil + 1$

so

$\lceil \frac ml\rceil = 1 $

And $\frac ml \le 1$

Comment: So in my question can I say  that $\lfloor \frac{-m}l \rfloor = -1$ ?

Comment: Yes, which means $-1 \le \frac {-m}l < 0$ and $0 < \frac ml \le 1$ and $\lceil \frac ml \rceil = 1$ and so $\frac ml \le 1$.  Somewhere you made an error and tossed out the $m = 0$ case (or I did) but floor function function, for the exact same reasons as less than/greater than inequalities, do not distribute over subtraction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how the *heck* did that get editted as such.  I swear to God and I distinctly remember typing "and $\frac ml \le 1$".  And yet somehow I look at it and I see the utterly irrelevent $1 \le \lceil \frac ml \rceil$ typed there.  ... so you know how sometimes your are typing and you are *thinking* one thing but your eye sees something else so you type that instead and because you are *thinking* one thing you absolutely can not see that you typed something entirely different?  That must have happened but ... it's really bizaar because I wasn't thinking *anything* of the sort.

Comment: Okay, I meant to imply I was stripping off the ceiling signs.  But because I was cutting and pasting I left them on.  I originally meant to type $\frac ml < 1$ but I got dyslexic and reversed the order and wrote $1 < \frac ml$ (except I left the ceiling signs on).  Then I realized that I assumed strict inequatily so I edited so it wasn't a strict inequality.  The result ... a complete WTF.